# Redirect in combination with a rewrite condition in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I've got a cms-driven website, with no option to change the code. What I want to accomplish is creating friendly url's, using only apaches mod-rewrite engine.

The problem is I'm creating an infinite loop, because I first redirect the original url (index.php?id=21) to a friendly one (/friendly/) and then rewrite the '/friendly' part back to 'id=21'

I know there should be an extra condition or parameter to avoid looping in this case, but I can´t get one of the possible solutions to work.

Here´s the code:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^id=21$ [NC]
RewriteRule /* /peuterspeelzaal? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^peuterspeelzaal$ index.php?id=21 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) in *THE_REQUEST* to see what originally has been requested:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\?id=21\  [NC]
RewriteRule /* /peuterspeelzaal? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^peuterspeelzaal$ index.php?id=21 [L]
```

Comment: I didn't know about the request line, but it seems this actually works. Just out of curiosity, what exactly makes that this code works and mine doesn't?

Comment: @Robbert van den Bogerd: When a rule is applied, the URI is changed. And the *L* flag implies a restart of the rewriting process with the new URI. That causes a infinite redirection as both rules create a new URI that is accepted by the other rule.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are rewriting in both directions to ensure that old links are redirected to the new friendly urls?

You could just add a dummy parameter to all your "friendly" rewrites so that they don't match the other rule:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^id=21$ [NC]
RewriteRule /* /peuterspeelzaal? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^peuterspeelzaal$ index.php?id=21&dummy=1 [L]
```

Comment: Good suggestion, however this seems more like a hack then a proper solution. But hey, it works!